# Java: Order a collection according to subtype

Tags: java, types, comparator

Not quite sure how I should attack this. I need to create a `Comparator` for a class called `Record`. These records have a time I will use, but if the time is the same, I need to order them depending on their type. Say for example we have the following `Record` subtypes:

- `AaRecord`
- `BbRecord`
- `CcRecord`
- `DdRecord`

Now, given a collection with a number of these, I need to order them so that for example all `CcRecord` come before `BbRecord` followed by `AaRecord` and finally `DdRecord`. What is a good and clean way of doing this?

Just to be clear, I can't use the names of the types to do this, as they could be anything. It's going to be used to process a list of records in the correct order.

```
public class RecordComparator implements Comparator<Record>
{
   @Override
   public int compare(Record x, Record y)
   {
      // First compare times
      int result = x.getTime().compareTo(y.getTime());
      if(result != 0)
         return result;

      // Then somehow compare types...

   }
}
```

Comment: What would be the criterion to decide the order of the subtypes?

Comment: @Paŭlo It's pretty much just defined in an "arbitrary" spec. If you consider CRUD, then a logical order would be first to Create, then Update, then Read and finally Delete.

Comment: Yeah, then you must delegate to this order on the subtypes. Etienne was quicker than me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a `Map<Class, Integer>` containing the sort orders for all the types, and then do this:

```
@Override
public int compare(Record x, Record y)
{
   // First compare times
   int result = x.getTime().compareTo(y.getTime());
   if(result != 0)
      return result;

   // sortOrders is your map
   return sortOrders.get(x.getClass()).compareTo(sortOrders.get(y.getClass()));
}
```

Or something like that.

Keep in mind that it doesn't *have* to be integers.

Comment: Went for this solution rather than a method on each type, since the order doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the types themselves. More like an... outside ordering specific to this purpose :)

Comment: Don't forget to handle the case where either type is not registered in the map...

Answer (score 0):

How about having a method that establishes order of the type, for example:

```
public abstract class Record
{
    public abstract int getRecordOrdinal();
}

public abstract class AaRecord extends Record
{
    @Override
    public int getRecordOrdinal() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public abstract class BbRecord extends Record
{
    @Override
    public int getRecordOrdinal() {
        return 2;
    }
}

//etc

public class RecordComparator implements Comparator<Record>
{
   @Override
   public int compare(Record x, Record y)
   {
      // First compare times
      int result = x.getTime().compareTo(y.getTime());
      if(result != 0)
         return result;

      return y.getRecordOrdinal() - x.getRecordOrdinal();
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but think I in this specific case prefer to have the ordering defined in a single place :)

Answer (score 0):

Although this sounds like you let us do your work, here is the outline of how to solve the problem:

(1) Extend your Record class for one abstract method getSortOrder()

```
public abstract class Record {
    public abstract int getSortOrder();
}
```

(2) Implement this method in your your subtypes AaRecord, BbRecord, CcRecord, ... as how you want them to be ordered, e.g.

```
public class AaRecord {
    @Override
    public int getSortOrder() {return 0; }
}

public class BbRecord {
    @Override
    public int getSortOrder() {return 1; }
}
```

And so on.

(3) RecordComparator implementation

```
public class RecordComparator implements Comparator<Record>
    {
       @Override
       public int compare(Record x, Record y)
       {
          // First compare times
          int result = x.getTime().compareTo(y.getTime());
          if(result != 0)
             return result;

          // Compare types
          return x.getSortOrder() - y.getSortOrder();
       }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can define an extra interface Sortable { int getSortOrder(); } and have Record implement it.

Comment: My goal wasn't to get others to do my work. I simply couldn't think of a smart way of doing it that didn't include a whole bunch of `if`s, which of course would be a nightmare and a mess...